# CursorAdapter not notified when ContentProvider deletes a row

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In the delete method of my `ContentProvider`, I have this notification instruction:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(url, null);
```

`CursorAdapters` does not refresh the view when the user deletes something.

What's wrong?
It works for insert and update operations.

Comment: try to implement the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but for anyone else, you should call

```
cursor.setNotificationUri()
```

in the query() method of your content provider before returning the cursor to the caller.

For example in the android contacts content provider: 
[ContactsProvider2.java](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java#6496%20%22ContactsProvider2.java)

This is because the [CursorAdapter.java](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#182) class registers a content observer on the cursor to requery on change.

Edit: reading your question again, that may not have been the problem.